# CKEditor strip/filter HTML comments?

Tags: ckeditor

I see a lot about this smart `Advanced Content Filter`, but it's too smart, it handles HTML elements and doesn't let me do custom filtering. I can't figure out how to strip all inserted HTML comments.

Answer (score 4):

Advanced Content Filter does not touch comments. It only filters HTML elements, nothing more.

If you want to strip all comments, then using [dataProcessor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor)'s filters will be the best choice.

For example to filter them out on input:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function( evt ) {
            evt.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
                comment: function() {
                    return false;
                }
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: anyway to use disallowedContent to do the same instead of dataProcessor?