# CKEditor replaces html comments issue

Tags: ckeditor

I tried to use angularjs' ng-repeat functionality inside a widget plugin. ng-repeat uses html comment nodes to track its work. However since the comments are processed by CKEditor and replaced by something like this
`<!--{cke_protected}{C}%3C!%2D%2D%20ngRepeat%3A%20obj%20in%20content%20%2D%2D%3E-->` which breaks the ng-repeat.
What can I do to prevent CKEditor from processing the comments? I tried to add some tags in `config.protectedSource` or doing the reverse of [CKEditor strip/filter HTML comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252237/ckeditor-strip-filter-html-comments), but without any success. Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to use Angular inside CKEditor? If so (and this is the only situation where you could be concerned by CKEditor protecting comments **inside** itself) - you're doing a wrong thing. CKEditor must have control over the data loaded into it and it's even hard to predict what will happen if Angular starts affecting the data.